# C# WPF Very slow application launch

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, optimization

I've wrote a simple `.net WPF` application(contains only 2 small windows), but its launch is too slow - about 10-20 seconds!

**Profiler says:**

- `Main->RunInternal`(56%)
- `Main->RunInternal->ctor->LoadBaml`(32%)

Biggest part of application load time - is body of `Main->RunInternal` function, this isn't my function and i don't know what they makes. **Can their execution time somehow be optimized?**

Loading Baml markup it takes 32% of all time, but my program have only 3 XAML files and they are containing less than 100 lines of code. **Why does this action take so long?**

Before asking I have read and tried these tricks, but they didn't help me:

- [WPF application slow on startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086692/wpf-application-slow-on-startup)
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656914.aspx

So, how can I speed up the start time of my application?

Thanks.

**PS.** I've tested this program on two similar computers and the result is a same.

Comment: Performance optimization is not really something you can do objectively, without a real context. Unless you provide some code, I'm affraid there is not many people that will be able to help you.

Comment: Are there binding errors? They can slow down your application dramatically.

Comment: There is no any binding errors and warnings...

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2007/10/10/improving-wpf-applications-startup-time.aspx - in my limited experience its just WPF being slow, and the solution is to add a splash screen, to provide some indication to the user

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WPF warm AppDomain startup performance (Application.RunInternal, XamlReader.LoadBaml)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610009/wpf-warm-appdomain-startup-performance-application-runinternal-xamlreader-load)

Answer (score 4):

Look at the article mentioned in the comments above.

I would suppose it is 8, (Authenticode), it depends on what assemblies you are referencing

Comment: I tested as suggested following itme 8 in the mentioned article, it reduces my app startup time from 16-20s to 3s.

Comment: Was this referring to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2007/10/10/improving-wpf-applications-startup-time.aspx ?  That seems to no longer exist

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. Google with RunInternal gives me nothing.

I then tried to backup my previous codes and **delete assemblies and files until there was only a window left.**

Then it worked -- the startup time was shortened from 10 sec to 1 sec!

This time, the profiler showed only **System.Windows.Application.Run()** instead of RunInternal

It's very strange that for this computer, even after re-importing the bugged(slow) version, it worked correctly! whereas my laptop, which did not go through the fixing above still boots the program for 10+ sec.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that the project itself was located on the network drive. So the app has to do a whole round trip to the destination drive located 500 miles away from my location and back, compile everything - so surely it was taking all the time. I looked at other issues but this was the one in my case.

**Make sure you project is located locally** before you try any other things.